# Deleting a specific node from a tree

Tags: python

Below is a program that I am working on involving trees. I am currently trying to be able to delete a specific node from created tree. Can someone offer some suggestions on what I am doing wrong? The code in question is def remove portion. The rest of it is working correctly.

```
    def remove(self, value):
        if self.root and self.root.value == value:  # special case for removing the root
            self.root = self.root.delete()
            return

        else:  # general case, removing a child node of some parent
            parent = self.root
            while parent:
                if value < parent.value:
                    child = parent.left
                    if child and child.value == value:
                        parent.left = child.delete()
                        return
                    parent = child
                else:
                    child = parent.right
                    if child and child.value == value:
                        parent.right = child.delete()
                        return
                    parent = child
```

Comment: In future include the traceback I just added from the start.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `self.root.value` not existing; the attribute you probably wanted is called `data`, not `value`.

Next, your `Node` objects have no `delete()` method, so that'll fail as well. Either add that method to the node (promoting either their left or right attribute and rebalancing their subtree), or do all that work in your `Tree.remove()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: you tried to access the `value` attribute of a `Node`, but there isn't one; there is one called `data`, which is maybe what you meant.